# Symmetric difference under injective mappings

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My problem is following:

Let $f:\mathbb R^\infty \to \mathbb R^\infty $ be injective.

Show, that $f(C \triangle D)=f(C)$ $\triangle$ $f(D)$, where $\triangle$ is the symmetric difference, defined as $ A \triangle B := (A\backslash B) \cup (B\backslash A)=(A \cup B) \backslash(A \cap B)$.

Comment: Please remind us uncultured people of what $\mathbb R^{\infty}$ is.

Comment: Use double inclusion.  What are you stuck on?

Comment: $\mathbb R^\infty$ means the infinite Cartesian product of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Double-inclusion:
So let $x \in  f(C \triangle D)$. Then $f^{-1}(x) \in C \triangle D$. But what comes next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\subset$:

Let $x \in f(C \Delta D)$. Then $x=f(y)$ for some $y \in C \Delta D \subset C \cup D$. Then,
$$x \in f(C) \cup f(D)$$

Assume now by contradiction that $x \in f(C) \cap f(D)$. Then $x=f(y_1)$ for some $z_1 \in C$ and $x=f(y_2)$ for some $z_2 \in D$. Since $f$ is 1-1, we have $y=z_1=z_2 \in C \cap D$ contradicting the fact that $y \in C \Delta D$.

$\supset$:

Let $x \in f(C) \Delta f(D)$. Then $x \in f(C) \cup f(D)$ and hence $x =f(y)$ for some $y \in C \cup D$.

We claim that $y \in C \Delta D$. Indeed, if we assume by contradiction that $y \notin C \Delta D$ then $y \in C\cap D$ and hence $x=f(y) \in f(C) \cap f(D)$ contradiction.